# новый шаблон для консольного приложения

Tags: c#, консоль, .net-6

Меня мучает вопрос, зачем было сделано это вообще, и как теперь писать новые методы для класса Program так чтобы оно всё это не пихало по умолчанию в main метод.
Прочёл статью [top level templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) ответа так и не нашёл на свой вопрос, подсказали что надо выбирать .net 5.0 и тогда будет генерироваться старый шаблон, но меня такое не устраивает, помогите кто знает

Comment: Никто не мешает добавить класс Program и статический Main вручную. Работать будет, как в старые добрые. Методы на верхнем уровне тоже можно добавлять.

Comment: @aepot а добавлять это всё ручками, или может можно просто кнопку какую-то нажать, ручками я заколебусь писать каждый раз

Comment: Есть стандартные макросы Visual Studio типа `prop` (напишите и нажмите Tab), в их состав можно включить все что угодно, создайте свой макрос, который добавит необходимый код.

Comment: Создайте [шаблон проекта](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022), содержащий необходимое вам. И потом используйте его.